# Look Up a value on another sheet with Variable Name in Excel

Tags: excel

I have found many answers to this similar questions and yet I cannot get this formula to work.

I have a code in Cell B2 which i need to look up on another sheet. The name of this sheet is in Cell A2, and the information I need to copy is in column E of the other sheet. Here is the formula that I am trying to use however it is coming back with a #N/A Error.

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,INDIRECT("'"& A2 & "'!$E$1:$E$100"), 5, FALSE)
```

Anyone have any idea why I am not getting any information through?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you ever feel for an Index + Match solution.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"& A2 &"'!$A$1:$E$100"),MATCH(B2,INDIRECT("'"& A2 &"'!$A$1:$A$100"),0),5)
```

Comment: You can't return the fifth column's value from E:E.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the string concatenation and expand the columns so that you can return in the 5th column's information.

```
=VLOOKUP($B2, INDIRECT("'"& A2 & "'!A1:E100"), 5, FALSE)
```

In the above, B2 is looked up in column A of the lookup range (the first column in the lookup range) and the corresponding value from column E (the fifth column in the range) is returned. VLOOKUP always looks in the first column and returns the corresponding value from the column noted by the third argument but the lookup range has to have at least that many columns.

You don't need $ absolute reference markers when you are using a string to reference within INDIRECT.

Comment: You are right!!!! It doesn't search in the first column for the lookup value! Nice catch!

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to mention, I'm searching in column E which is where the codes are from the cells in B column on original sheet, hence why the column E is searched

Comment: =VLOOKUP($B2, INDIRECT("'"& A2 & "'!A1:F100"), 6, FALSE)

This is what I have now but it still returns #N/A. I did a sanity check and did a manual CTRL+F on the sheet that I'm searching and it does find the value which is why this is even more confusing for me

Comment: It sounds like you want to search through column E. What column are you trying to return a value from?